# SQL Query Showing 4x Records

Tags: sql, select

The following statement works properly but shows each record 4 times. Repeated; I know the relationship is wrong but no idea how to fix it? Apologies if this is simple and i've missed it.

```
SELECT Customers.First_Name, Customers.Last_Name, Plants.Common_Name, Plants.Flower_Colour, Plants.Flowering_Season, Staff.First_Name, Staff.Last_Name
FROM Customers, Plants, Orders, Staff
INNER JOIN Orders AS t2 ON t2.Order_ID = Staff.Order_ID
WHERE Orders.Order_Date
BETWEEN  '2011/01/01'
AND  '2013/03/01'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are generating a Cartesian product between the tables since you have not provided join syntax between any of the tables:

```
SELECT c.First_Name, c.Last_Name, 
    p.Common_Name, p.Flower_Colour, p.Flowering_Season, 
    s.First_Name, s.Last_Name
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o
    on c.customerId = o.customer_id 
INNER JOIN  Plants p
    on o.plant_id = p.plant_id
INNER JOIN Staff s
    ON o.Order_ID = s.Order_ID
WHERE o.Order_Date BETWEEN  '2011/01/01' AND  '2013/03/01'
```

*Note:* I am guessing on column names for the joins

Here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) that can help in learning the correct syntax

Comment: +1 . . . This is the right answer, with a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the `FROM...` clause you are doing a cross join - combining every customer with every plant with every order with every staff.

You should only mention one table in the `FROM` clause and then connect the other ones with `INNER JOINS` to only get related records.

I don't know exactly how your database looks like, but something like this:

```
SELECT Customers.First_Name, Customers.Last_Name, Plants.Common_Name,
Plants.Flower_Colour, Plants.Flowering_Season, Staff.First_Name, Staff.Last_Name
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN Staff ON Staff.Staff_ID = Orders.Staff_ID
INNER JOIN Plants ON Plants.Plants_ID = Orders.Plants_ID
WHERE Orders.Order_Date
BETWEEN  '2011/01/01'
AND  '2013/03/01'
```

Comment: Actually, the query is doing a cross join, not a full outer join.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are selecting from four tables without any joins between them, and also because you are joining `Orders` twice. As the result, a *Cartesian product* is made.

Here is how you should fix it: re-write the theta join using the ANSI syntax, and provide proper join conditions:

```
SELECT Customers.First_Name, Customers.Last_Name, Plants.Common_Name, Plants.Flower_Colour, Plants.Flowering_Season, Staff.First_Name, Staff.Last_Name
FROM Customers
JOIN Plants ON ...
JOIN Orders ON ...
JOIN Staff ON ...
INNER JOIN Orders AS t2 ON t2.Order_ID = Staff.Order_ID
WHERE Orders.Order_Date BETWEEN  '2011/01/01' AND  '2013/03/01'
```

Replace `...` with proper join conditions; this should make the results look as expected.